# Attribution model in Google Analytics reports

Tags: google-analytics

We use standard and custom reporting in Google Analytics. But for our reports we need another attribution model. In https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1665189 we have found that  Analytics uses Last Non-Direct Click model by default when attributing conversion value in non-Multi-Channel Funnels reports. But what about switching to another default model? Multi-Channel Funnels and Model Comparison Tool are not suitable. We need custom report with First Interaction model.

Comment: This question is off topic as it's not about programming. Please post in Webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change model atribution in the analytics report API
but u canu use mcf API, and create custom model
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/?hl=ru
using dimension mcf:sourceMediumPath

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem and it seems that you cannot change default attribution model for all other reports then MFC in Google Analytics Standard. There are basically two ways to workaround though:

1. You can play with MFC/Attribution reports and change attribution
   models there and try to set up custom report with First Interaction
   model that satisfies your needs(but not all the dimensions/metrics will   be available).
2. You can stream hit level data to
   some other storage(Google BigQuery, Amazon RedShift etc), and build
   your attribution by your own from the raw data(but obviously some
   level of programming skills is required, http://noca.cz/githubgabq
   is a good python example to start with collecting data)